Uninstall default apps Windows 11 with Powershell
I am looking for a method to uninstall Windows store apps with Powershell.
The main apps that I want to uninstall are:
XBox, Spotify, Linkedin, Solitaire and hide Windows store by script.

The reason for that is that we have to set up those machines in a corporate environment, where we need to get rid of those apps, and we have a lot of pcs to prepare depending on the month.
I have already tried thing like this for xbox as an example:
get-appxpackage -allusers *xboxapp* | remove-appxpackage

But somehow, Windows 11 doesn't recognize any installed apps (Windows 10 did it correctly and we could install a lot of apps really quickly with a script that used to uninsall those unnecessary apps), but I can see they are installed when I click on the icon:

I also tried this:
$Junk = "xbox|phone|disney|skype|spotify|groove|solitaire|zune|mixedreality|tiktok|adobe|prime|soundrecorder|bingweather!3dviewer"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object {  $_.DisplayName -match $Junk  }| Format-Table  -Property DisplayName

But I get only this in return
DisplayName                   
-----------                   
AdobeAcrobatDCCoreApp         
Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal 
Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder
Microsoft.ZuneMusic           
Microsoft.ZuneVideo

Does anyone have any idea how to find those apps and uninstall those, which are somehow hidden in the Microsoft vortex :). Thanks

try this github repository to remove bloatware:
https://github.com/arcadesdude/BRU

Thanks Ikkxeer, Sounds awesome. Ill definetely check this tomorrow :).

I hope you find the repository useful for your purpose, if not, I can help you if you need to develop a specific script to remove apps
